# NSTimer 'time' issue

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer`and I am using the method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` but I would  like the time interval it takes as a parameter to be a function, not an explicit value. How could I do this?

My code looks like this:

```
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time(), target: self, selector: "doStuff", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The compiler complains with the first parameter `time()`

edit: the error is "extra argument 'selector' in call"

Comment: what is `time` function? and full error message please.

Comment: extra argument 'selector' in call"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you're getting *that* error, but `time()` is certainly not what you want for your time interval.  That's supposed to be the number of seconds between firings of the timer.  For something like a repeating animation timer that will typically be something like 1/30.0 or 1/60.0.

The `time` function (which, by the way, should take an argument) returns an integer that's the number of seconds since the "epoch."  On Mac OS X the epoch is 12:00 AM, UTC of January 1, 2001.

**Edit:** It sounds from your comment like you've defined your own `time` function.  I would first of all, change the name of your function to (say) `timeInterval` so it can't possibly collide with the system's `time` function.  And I would make sure your function returns an `NSTimeInterval`, as opposed to a `Float` or some other number type, like:

```
func timeInterval() -> (NSTimeInterval) {
    return 1/60.0
}

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval(), target: self, selector: "doStuff", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I want the time interval to change so I wrote a function to do this but `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` will not take it as the parameter for the timeInterval

Comment: Where is your `time` function defined?  There's a system `time` function, and I suspect the compiler is finding the system function and not yours.  Maybe try changing the name of your function to make sure there's no collision.

Comment: I'll change the name of my function and report back.

Comment: Make sure it returns `NSTimeInterval` too.  You didn't post your implementation so I can't tell, but when I tried it I got your same error when `timeInterval` returned `Float`, but not when it returned `NSTimeInterval` or when it returned `Double`.